# Passing props when rendering using h() with children on php laravel-mix

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I have case for vuejs component that need to be rendered using `php` with `laravel-mix`. Its accepting `role` props

```js
export default {
  name: 'ComponentOne',
  props: {
    role: [Number],
  },
  methods: {
    render(h) {
      return h(
        'div',
        {
          attrs: {
            id: 'component-one',
          }
        },
         this.$slots.default
      )
    },
  },
};
```

```php
<?php
  $role = 1;
?>

<div id="app">
  <component-one :role="<?php echo $role ?>" />
</div>
```

Due to some package usage, the components render need to be define as follow:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne.vue'
import SomePackage, { Wrapper, Reset } from '@somepackages'

Vue.use(SomePackage)

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(Wrapper, [h(Reset), h(ComponentOne)]),
}).$mount('#app')
```

so the `role` props instead passed to the `Wrapper` and the props on `ComponentOne` are `undefined`.

Is there a way to pass the props from `Wrapper` to `ComponentOne` without literally declaring it on `Wrapper`?

I've been trying using `provide` and `inject`, and it somewhat working. But I want to know if there is another way that I not know.

```js
export default {
  name: 'ComponentOne',
  provide() {
    return { role: this.role };
  },
  inject: ['role'],
  props: {
    role: [Number],
  },
  methods: {
    render(h) {
      return h(
        'div',
        {
          attrs: {
            id: 'component-one',
          }
        },
         this.$slots.default
      )
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find a way to get props value from template.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne.vue'
import SomePackage, { Wrapper, Reset } from '@somepackages'

Vue.use(SomePackage)

new Vue({
  render: function (h) {
    const allProps = Object.keys(ComponentOne.props).reduce((carry, key) => {
      carry[key] = this.$vnode?.componentOptions?.propsData?.[key]
      return carry;
    }, {});
    return h(Wrapper, [h(reset), h(ComponentOne, { props: { ...allProps } })]
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

`this.$vnode` is object from virtual node in which already rendered on php. So I can get props value initiated on the element.

I need to change render from arrow function to function to be able to get `this` context.